# how can i show group attribute name in product page?

Tags: product-attribute, group

i am using magento 1.9.1.1 
i am showing attributes in product page but that list without showing attribute's group name
how can i show Group attribute name with that attributes ?

Comment: What is "group attribute name"? Do you want to group the attributes in the frontend as they are grouped in the admin panel?

Comment: please see this link [link] http://www.webguys.de/magento/attributes-als-attribute-set-im-webshop-darstellen/ [/link]  i want to do this in magento 1.9.1.1

Comment: please if you have good answer or link of that toturial say to me. i was search this problem but don't find any solution for this